# Grep recursively through zipped files

Tags: unix, grep, find

I have a set of zip files with multiple levels of directories in them. I want to find some content from a text file in one of those directories which can be in any of the zip files. If the files are unzipped, I would use the following

```
grep -r 'pattern' path
```

I tried using `zgrep` but it said that the option `-r` isn't supported. Is there a way to grep through the zipped files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try with find command like:

```
find mydir -type f -name "*log.gz" -exec zgrep "pattern" {} \;
```

Above command will search for pattern in files named "*log.gz" residing in either mydir or sub directories within mydir.

Comment: Hi almas, can you explain what mydir here is? Is it the path of the zip files? I tried this and this isn't working.

Comment: @pogo have added comment in the answer. When you say isn't working what's not working?